# Add class depending on image dimensions (Jekyll)

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to add a specific class to an image in Jekyll depending on the image's dimensions. Basically I want to loop through a couple of images in a folder and add the correct class to the image depending on if the image is in landscape or portrait mode (i.e. if the width is bigger than the height and vice versa).

I've tried to do it with JavaScript, but I would prefer a method that would add the classes during the build process of the site instead of on page load.

This is the image loop:

```
<div class="model-gallery">
{% capture gallery_path %}pics/models/gallery/{{ page.title | slugify | replace: '-','' | replace: 'å','a' | replace: 'ä','a' | replace: 'ö','o' }}{% endcapture %}
{% for image in site.static_files %}
    {% if image.path contains gallery_path %}
        {{image.size}}
        <img class="gallery-item" src="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ image.path }}" alt="{{page.title}}, {{site.title}}" />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of having all the pictures in `.../gallery/`, you could divide them into `.../gallery/landscape/` and `.../gallery/portrait/`. You would have separate loops, but it would let you add classes specific to each type of picture.

Comment: That's an option, but I want them to loop in a specific order. So I don't want a chunk of portrait images to be looped through first and then the landscape images. But maybe there's a way to loop through them in a mixed order regardless?

Comment: So there's the `sample` filter for Liquid. You could have the separate loops and after each iteration add the image to an array. Then, use the `sample` filter to get a random pick from the array. `{{ images | sample }}` or `{{ images | sample: 4}}` to get 1 or 4 images. 

It's not ideal since the order is random, but it would allow you to go through in a mixed order.